# Error regarding 'webBluetooth' in developer tools(console) of Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, developer-tools

Whenever I open `developer tools` in my `Google-Chrome` browser, I get this strange error in the console:

> The 'WebBluetooth' feature is currently enabled in limited trials. Please see [Phosphor console URL] for information on enabling a trial for your site.

I get total 28 instances of this error in every tab that I open. I checked firefox and Internet Explorer but didn't find the same there.

What is this error about and how do I solve it? *I haven't yet noticed any side-effects regarding browser's performance*. But its always annoying to see any errors in the console and it's worse when it gets mixed up with other errors on the console.

Comment: Do you have the beta/Canary versions of Chrome? If so, it sounds like a message informing your about a feature, not an error. I wouldn't be worried.

Comment: `Version 50.0.2661.26 beta-m (64-bit)` yeah its beta version.